# Flask: permanently run function/script on server

Tags: flask, server, console, spyder

Im pretty new to Flask.

I have written a complex text analysis function in Python. The first run of my function takes quite some time to run (a few minutes). However, when this first run is finished I can specify input via my Spyder Console and the next search runs take only a few seconds. So the script is very fast once the function is loaded.

Now I would like to go online with this project: i.e. users of my webpage can specify the input and perform the analysis themselves. Therefore I'm writing a Flask app. However, the website works very slow because every single run search the Python script has to start from te beginning.

Therefore my question is: is it possible in Flask to run a script permanently 24/7 on my server on the background so I have to start the function on my server only once (like in Spyder). Subsequently the users specify their search input in my home.html form, their input is sent to the server and the script on the server immediately returns the results (like locally in my Spyder Console) because the script is already running on the server and therefore can immediately perform the search instead of first starting up the function over and over again for every new search request?

Any help would be useful if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible - though you didn't state your OS. You can presumably start your Python script using `systemd` and `systemctl` at server boot-time - completely independently of anything else. It should then listen, waiting for socket connections.

In your `flask` app, as each user makes a request, open a socket connecting to your Python script, pass in the parameters down the socket and then wait for the response and send it on to the client.